# Confusing language Statistic R

Tags: r, regression

I am having difficulty comprehending what the question is asking me to do. The first part of the question was easy to follow but then, I'm not sure what is being asked. Please see:

> Q1: Using the Heights (library alr4) data, create a construction set by selecting approximately 2/3 of the rows of the data file at random. The remaining 1/3 of the rows will comprise the validation set.

I solved this question by:

```
Heights <- Heights %>% mutate(id = row_number())

constructionSet <- sample_frac(Heights, size = 0.66) #This code randomly samples 2/3 rd portion without replacement.

validationSet <- anti_join(Heights, constructionSet, by = 'id')
```

> Q2: Obtain predictions from the model fit to the construction set for the values of Mheight in the validation set. Compute and report the average squared residual. The square root of this quantity is an estimate of the average prediction error.

This language is too complex for me to decipher. What I got from this question:

a) make a model of the construction set: `model <- lm(dheight ~ mheight, data = constructionSet)`

b) predict how that model will extrapolate values for the data in the validation set:

`predict(model, newdata = validationSet)`

c) calculate average squared residual (of which model?): I am assuming that it wants me to calculate the residuals for the model which used "construction set". In that case,

```
modelParams <- augment(model) #Using broom library

averagePredictionError <- sqrt(mean((modelParams$.resid)^2))
```

Not sure if I am understanding this correctly. The next question is completely unclear.

> Q3: As an alternative to cross-validation in this problem, use the fitted model based on the construction set to obtain predictions and the standard error of prediction for each of the rows in the validation set. Then compute the average squared prediction error and its square root. Compare with the results of the last subproblem.

Can someone break down this question. I feel like that's exactly what I have done in the previous problem.

Comment: Just as a comment, I cannot see that your model should incorporate the daughters' heights. Hence, `mod <- lm(mheight~1, data=constructionSet)`, which is equivalent to `mean(constructionSet[,"mheight"])` would be a valid interpretation of the question IMHO.

Comment: @KarstenW. The data set and the problem is trying to understand the effect of mother's height on daughter's height. Also, can you explain what 1 represents here?

Comment: I think you have to ask the person who developed this set of questions about what was intended, or provide more context (e.g., source of the questions, more of the content of a document associated with these  questions). It looks like it might have come from some document regarding cross-validation, but none of the questions directly address cross-validation. Also, one hint: always set a seed and report what you set before you take a sample so that others can reproduce the results.